# Cannot find an initializer for type

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, healthkit

```
    let endDate = NSDate()
    let startDate = NSDate()
    let v : Float?
    let stepsCount:HKQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)!
    let predicate:NSPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, options: .None)

    let query = HKQuantitySample(sampleType: stepsCount, predicate: predicate, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil, resultsHandler: {
        (query, results, error) in
        if results == nil {
            print(error)
        }
        v = result.first.Quantity

    })
    healthStore.executeQuery(query)
```

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'HKQuantitySample' that accepts
>   an argument list of type '(sampleType: HKQuantityType, predicate:
>   NSPredicate, limit: Int, sortDescriptors: nil, resultsHandler: (_, _,
>   _) -> _)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `HKQuantitySample` with `HKSampleQuery` and it will work fine.

For more Info refer [THIS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86336/ios-8-healthkit-swift-getting-started) tutorial.

Where you can find sample code like:

```
func readMostRecentSample(sampleType:HKSampleType , completion: ((HKSample!, NSError!) -> Void)!)
{

  // 1. Build the Predicate
  let past = NSDate.distantPast() as! NSDate
  let now   = NSDate()
  let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(past, endDate:now, options: .None)

  // 2. Build the sort descriptor to return the samples in descending order
  let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
  // 3. we want to limit the number of samples returned by the query to just 1 (the most recent)
  let limit = 1

  // 4. Build samples query
  let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: mostRecentPredicate, limit: limit, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor])
    { (sampleQuery, results, error ) -> Void in

      if let queryError = error {
        completion(nil,error)
        return;
      }

      // Get the first sample
      let mostRecentSample = results.first as? HKQuantitySample

      // Execute the completion closure
      if completion != nil {
        completion(mostRecentSample,nil)
      }
  }
  // 5. Execute the Query
  self.healthKitStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation doesn't talk about any initializer like the one you are providing… Even looked in the Beta docs and didn't found anything about the one you are trying to call.

Please look here for existing `HKQuantitySample` initializers available :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKQuantitySample_Class/

*See Dharmesh Kheni's answer for the correct way to create a query :).*